# Prove that $C(a) $ ={$r \in R : ra = ar$} is a subring of $R$ containing $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

For a fixed element $a \in R$ define $C(a)$ ={$r \in R : ra = ar$}. Prove that $C(a)$ is a subring of $R$ containing $a$.

**attempt:** Recall by definition ,  $B$ is a subring of $A$ if and only if $B$ is closed under subtraction and multiplication.

Then Suppose $r,c \in C(a)$. Then its closed under the subtraction (that is if and only if $C(a)$ is closed with respect to both addition and negatives.

Closed under +

$(r+c)a = ra + ca = ar + ac = a(r + c)$

Closed under

Likewise under multiplication: 
$(rc)a = r(ca) = r(ca) = (ra)c = (ar)c = a(rc)$.

Then from the closure of addition we have $ra + ca = ar + ac$. So 
$ra = ar$ and $ca = ac$, thus $a \in C(a)$ for all $r\in R$, and $-c \in C(a)$. so $C(a)$ is a subring of $R$.

Can someone please verify this? Any help or better approach would be really appreciated it ! thanks.

Comment: $B$ should also be nonempty and I'm sure you've verified that $a\in C(a)$. Otherwise, this looks fine.

Comment: This don't hold in a ring without $1$.

Comment: so I also need to check it has the identity?

Comment: I think many books let you assume that rings have $1$, which is important to your proof. A counterexample is $C(2)$ in the ring of even integers mod $12$ (you can check that $2\not\in C(2)$).

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefishm I don't understand you're example. Could you explain further?

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish $a\in C(a)$ holds in any ring, unital or not, because $a$ commutes with itself.

Comment: Ahhh - I was looking at the set of $ar$ and $ra$ for each $r$ that commutes with $a$. My apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in C (a)$. Then $ac=ca$. Now we have $-ca=-(ca)=-(ac)=-ac=a (-c)$. This shows that $-c\in C (a)$, and the above argument completes the proof.